# PHP - return each result from fetchAll

Tags: php

I am trying to print my result data returned from the fetchAll function. How can i bind the name and desc variable to the returned results.

```
 <?php
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY DateAdded DESC LIMIT 4");
$get->execute(); 
$results = $get ->fetchAll(); 

  foreach($results as $result){ ?>
              $name = $result['Name'];
              $desc= $result['Desc'];
           <h4><?php echo $name ?></h4>
           <h4><?php echo $desc?></h4>

         <?php
         }
  ?>
```

Comment: `?>` should be after `$desc= $result['Desc'];`. Make an effort, learn php syntax carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$results = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach($results as $key => $value){ ?>
   echo '<h4>'.$value['name'].'</h4>
       <h4>'.$value['desc'].'</h4>';         
}
```

You also had a space between `$get` and `->fetchAll()`

You might want to remove the php closing tag `?>` as it might give you problems when including.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fetch all results at once to do that. It's better to use `fetch` method for that task.

```
while ($row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

And about main problem here, you are missing closing tag after `$result['Desc'];`